# The Principal is resposible for the monitoring of the attendance of all students. [Why is it not 'all the students'?]

Tags: definite-articles

Why is ***all students*** here not ***all the students***?

My logic is like so:

(1) ***The Principal***: a generic noun, with '***Principal***' as a prototypical representation of principals in general, with 'the' in front of it to signal he is the principal of a prototypical school.

(2) ***all the students***: ***students*** are of the prototypical school; therefore, ***the students***.

I'm very much at a loss. Is this just omission of the article, and on the special side to make it sound more stilted?

> ***The Principal*** is responsible for the accurate recording and rigorous monitoring of the attendance of **all students** and for
>   implementing appropriate strategies to restore attendance if there are
>   attendance issues. [excerpted from a manual of attendance policy by
>   Government of Western Australia]

---

After a while, I am now thinking ....

Would the rationale be anything like this? : **all students** represents {students of the untold school that represents any school} (in general), and a part that would tell you that the students go to the school is not stated because the readers would naturally understand it without it explicitly written.

> The Principal is responsible for the accurate recording and rigorous
>   monitoring of the attendance of **all students** (**that go to his school**)
>   (in general) and for implementing appropriate strategies to restore
>   attendance if there are attendance issues. [excerpted from a manual of
>   attendance policy by Government of Western Australia]

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically both usages are possible.

All is a determiner and predeterminer. ([ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/de/definition/englisch/all))

> all PREDETERMINER, DETERMINATOR & PRONOMEN

Therefore it acts as predeterminer in **all the students** and as central determiner in **all students**. The article 'the' is also a determiner.

As [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+students%2C+all+the+students&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20students%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20the%20students%3B%2Cc0) shows the shorter variant is more common.

---

I guess it's always the context that determines the sum of **all students**, which is by definition to the whole, nobody would assume that the local principal is responsible for all students worldwide.